# Objetos, especificar según índice

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde tengo diferentes fotos y donde quiero resaltar las elegidas.

El objeto que uso tiene el siguiente formato:

`[ { url:"http..1." fav:"true" } { url:"http...2" fav:"false" } ]`

El estado `const [fav, setFav] = useState(false);`.

La función *handle*:

```
const handleFav = () => {
    setFav(!fav);
};
```

Y el botón icono:

```
<IconButton
     className={classes.fav}
     value={data.url}
     onClick={() => {handleFav()}}>
<Icon>
  {fav ? 'estrella','bordeEstrella'}
</Icon>

  </IconButton>
```

El problema que me surge es que no estoy seleccionando individualmente los elementos que quiero destacar, entonces cuando pongo favorito en una, instantáneamente quedan todas como favoritas.
Necesito saber como se filtra correctamente esa información.

Intente de la siguiente manera y no me funciona:

```
const handleFav = (url) => {
 return data.find(function(url){
 url.fav === fav
 setFav(!fav);
}
```

y con:

```
const handleFav = (url) => {
 Array.from(data).forEach(url =>{      
 url = event.target.value
 fav = data[url].fav
 setFav(!fav);
 })
};
```

Comment: Pista: usa el evento asociado al `onclick` que tienes, no uso react asi que es lo unico que te puedo decir, ya que segun entiendo en React la cosa con los eventos cambia un poco, no es exactamente igual que con Angular

Comment: Hola gracias. Pero el evento asociado esta bien, por eso me funciona el poner todas las fotos como favoritas y viceversa. Lo que tengo mal es la funcion Handle que se usa solo javaScript y con la cual no he logrado seleccionar individualmente la foto.

Comment: Tienes que ir manejando la condición en base al objeto seleccionado (index)...

Comment: por lo que veo `handleFav = (url)` recive un argumento pero no veo que se le pase algun parametro... podrias corregir pasando el favorito asi `onClick={() => {handleFav(data.url)}}` ahora corregimos la funcion `const handleFav = (urlF) => {
 return data.find(function(url){
 url.fav === urlF
 setFav(!url.fav);
}`

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en que la variable de estado `fav` es una variable global para todos los items de la iteracion (suponiendo que estas haciendo una iteracion con un map en la vista de la data (lo mas probable y que he entendido es que lo estas haciendo)), sabiendo que la data se conforma por `{url: '...', fav: 'true|false'}`, deberias agregar un campo `id` (para hacer esto), la data debe quedar algo asi: `{id: id, url: url, fav: 'true|false', podemos hacer algo como lo siguiente

```js
const FatherComponent = () => {
  const [completeArray, setCompleteArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCompleteArray(/* The array obtained by the api */);
    setCompleteArray(completeArray.map((item, idx) => ({...item, id: idx}));
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
    {
      completeArray.map((item, idx) => (
        <ChildComponent
          data={item}
          setCompleteArray={setCompleteArray}
          completeArray={completeArray}
        />
      ))
    }
    ...
  );
}

const ChildComponent = (data, completeArray, setCompleteArray) => {

  const handleStarClick = () => {
    setCompleteArray(completeArray.map((item, idx) => {
      if (item.id === data.id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          fav: !data.fav
        }
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
  }

...

  <IconButton ... onClick={handleStarClick}>
    <Icon>
      {{ data.fav === 'true' ? 'estrella' : 'borde_estrella' }}
    </Icon>
  </IconButton>

...

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, SI estas en lo cierto, hay un elemento padre con el cual estoy haciendo el map. Voy a intentar con los ejemplos que me dieron y luego les aviso que me funciono.

Comment: Esta bien... nos avisas que tal te va y si logras solucionar! Mucha suerte :D

Answer (score 1):

Como te indique en los comentarios, una opción es realizar el filtro mediante el índice del objeto seleccionado.

Lo que te está ocurriendo, es que al momento de querer *setear* la variable `true` o `false`, estás aplicando el nuevo valor a todos los elementos de tu arreglo, cuando lo que deberías hacer es mediante algún filtro - *como el id que te indico el colega en la otra respuesta, o el índice que es mi opción* -, puedas actualizar sólo el objeto seleccionado.

Algo así

```
const item = info.find((value, idx) => idx === index);
let clone = [...info];
clone[index].fav = !item.fav;

setInfo(clone);
```

Mediante el **index**, que envías por parámetro, realizar la búsqueda del objeto que seleccionaste y después simplemente cambias su valor basándote en el valor anterior

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/actualizacion-de-objeto-basado-en-su-indice-m8vry)** te dejo el ejemplo completo para tu análisis; nos comentas que tal te va :D

Comment: Muchas gracias.! lo voy a probar y aviso cuando lo haga funcionar. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de hacer el ejemplo.